# How to obtain a view's structure/query using OleDb?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I have an ASP.Net application that reads data from an Access 2010 database file (.mdb).

I can easily list all tables and views in the database like this:

```
string sql = "select name from msysobjects where type in (1,5)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,con);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dataTable);   // now dataTable contains all ojbects' names I have created in access
```

What I would like to inquire about is the structure of the tables/views without relying on Access. I.E, using external OleDb commands.

In Oracle, I could do so by running the command

```
describe table_name;
describe view_name;
describe procedure_name;
```

but how can it be done in MS Access?

Comment: Use GetSchema which gives list of tables and columns. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/getschema-and-schema-collections?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

As with all relational databases there are tables of tables (reflection data).  These are normally hidden, but you can Select * From msysObjects. Filtering on Type will allow you to distinguish tables from queries from forms from reports, but also allows distinguishing internal tables from mapped tables.

If you want them listed in the Navigation Pane, then right-click on the pane, select Navigation Options, and click the Show System Objects check box.